# issues related to getElementByTagName

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags, getelementsbytagname

I have two select tags in my page. Each of these have several options within. Now I want to access only the second select box, but since I have used getElementByTagName("options") so it is fetching only the first option tag.I am unable to access the second option tags.

My code is here:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect_two").selectedIndex;
  alert(document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

  Select your favorite fruit:
  <select id="mySelect_one">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
    <option value="banana">Banana</option>
  </select>

  <select id="mySelect_two">
    <option value="India">India</option>
    <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
    <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
    <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
  </select>

  <p>Click the button to return the value of the selected fruit.</p>

  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So select the options of the select, not the entire document.

Comment: how to do this? actually in my code I have mentioned getElementById("mySelect_two") but it is still fetching the options from select with id "mySelect_one"

Comment: so you already selected the element to get the index, do the same thing to get the options.

Comment: <script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect_two").selectedIndex;

alert(x);
alert(document.getElementById("mySelect_two").getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value); 
}
</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get elements by tag name on the select rather than entire document

```
function myFunction() 
{
    var select = document.getElementById("mySelect_two");
    var x = select.selectedIndex;
    alert(select.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value); 
}
```

Comment: thnx gurvinder,,,it is working

Answer (score 0):

with options

```
var sel = document.getElementById("mySelect_two");
var selectedIndex = sel.selectedIndex;
var value = sel.options[selectedIndex].value;
```

with getElementsByTagName

```
var sel = document.getElementById("mySelect_two");
var selectedIndex = sel.selectedIndex;
var value = sel.getElementsByTagName("option")[selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below script to get selected options value:

```js
var e = document.getElementById("mySelect_two");
var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
alert(str)
```

```html
<select id="mySelect_two">
<option value="India">India</option>
<option value="Nepal" selected>Nepal</option>
<option value="Spain">Spain</option>
<option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
</select>
```

Comment: sorry it is not working...You did not get my question. I asked it makes problem with multiple same tag name